# save file with different name in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am uploading one file that is kind of multipart. I want this file to save with different name.

1. tried with renameTo method but did not work.
2. tried moveto but did not work

below is my code
here graphic is multipart file

```
String picName     = graphic.getOriginalFilename();EN_LENGTH) + "." + graphic.getContentType();
        Path   dirLocation = Paths.get(dirPath);
        String newName = CommonUtil.getToken(Constants.STANDRAD_TOKEN_LENGTH) + "." + graphic.getContentType();
        try {
            InputStream is = graphic.getInputStream();
            Files.copy(is, dirLocation.resolve(picName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            boolean a = new File(dirLocation+picName).renameTo(new File(dirLocation+newName));
```

for security reasons I want it to save with different name.

Comment: Why are you not directly saving it with 'dirLocation+newName'?
What are the error messages, if there is one?

Comment: what do you mean by did not work? you should troubleshoot for those errors which you got while trying those approaches.

Comment: Thanks Nico for pointing it out. Actually I was trying for that but as new filename was not correct so it was not saving. Now fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by correcting the filename. The file name which I was generating randomly was not correct. it had some slash etc.